# SQL Case Statements with Where and Count Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, azure-sql-database, case

Unable to run this query. I want to get count of promoter and demoters for Sites.

```
SELECT 
    Site, COUNT(*) AS Count,
    CASE WHEN NPS <= 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS demoter,
    CASE WHEN NPS >= 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS promoter
FROM 
    [D998AA0_CXS].[APD_CXS].[SURVEY_DETAILS]
WHERE 
    [CaseNumber] NOT LIKE '%C%' 
    AND CONVERT(date, DateCompleted) BETWEEN '2022-08-29'  AND '2022-09-02'
    AND Region = 'United States' 
    AND Channel = 'Phone' 
    AND SkillCategory = 'Customer Service'
    AND SkillName IN ('Tracking', 'Universal', 'Shipping')
GROUP BY 
    Site
```

[image]

I tried running with count function but I get an error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
> Column 'D998AA0_CXS.APD_CXS.SURVEY_DETAILS.NPS' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Why are you using a `GROUP BY` when you have no aggregation?

Comment: The error could not be clearer, you are not aggregating the column `NPS`, eg with `max(expression)`

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough information in the question to provide a good answer; all we can do is guess. So here are two guessess:

First:

```
SELECT Site, COUNT(*) as Count,
    CASE WHEN NPS <= 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS demoter,
    CASE WHEN NPS >= 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS promoter
FROM [D998AA0_CXS].[APD_CXS].[SURVEY_DETAILS]
WHERE [CaseNumber] NOT LIKE '%C%' 
    AND CONVERT(date,DateCompleted) BETWEEN '2022-08-29'  AND '2022-09-02'
    AND Region = 'United States' and Channel = 'Phone' and SkillCategory = 'Customer Service'
    AND SkillName In ('Tracking','Universal','Shipping')
GROUP BY Site, NPS
```

Second:

```
SELECT Site, COUNT(*) as Count,
    CASE WHEN SUM(NPS) <= 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS demoter,
    CASE WHEN SUM(NPS) >= 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS promoter
FROM [D998AA0_CXS].[APD_CXS].[SURVEY_DETAILS]
WHERE [CaseNumber] NOT LIKE '%C%' 
    AND CONVERT(date,DateCompleted) BETWEEN '2022-08-29'  AND '2022-09-02'
    AND Region = 'United States' and Channel = 'Phone' and SkillCategory = 'Customer Service'
    AND SkillName In ('Tracking','Universal','Shipping')
GROUP BY Site
```

I expect **neither** of these are right, but they should at least run, and based on the results you see and how they differ from the original they could give you enough of a push to finish on your own.